# Sharing object between 2 classes

Tags: php, object-oriented

**edit**: I am thinking that dependency injection is the best approach.

I am struggling to wrap my head around being able to share an object between two classes. I want to be able to create only one instance of the object, `commonlib`  in my `main` class and then have the classes, `foo1` and `foo2`, to be able to mutually share the properties of the commonlib. `commonlib` is a 3rd party class which has a property `Queries` that will be **added** to in each child class of `bar`. This is why it is vital that only one instance is created. I create two separate queries in `foo1` and `foo2`.

This is my setup:

```
abstract class bar{
//common methods
}


class foo1 extends bar{
//add query to commonlib
}

class foo2 extends bar{
//add query to commonlib
}

class main {

    public $commonlib = new commonlib();

    public function start(){
    //goal is to share one instance of $this->commonlib between foo1 and foo2 
    //so that they can both add to the properites of $this->commonlib (global
    //between the two)

    //now execute all of the queries after foo1 and foo2 add their query
    $this->commonlib->RunQueries();

}



}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Approach 1: Use a property in `bar`

Make `commonlib` a property in `bar` and declare getters and setters. Share that one instance of `commonlib` that you declared in `main` between `foo1` and `foo2`.

```php
abstract class bar {
    protected $commonlib;
    
    public function __get($property) {
        if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
            return $this->$property;
        }
    }

    public function __set($property, $value) {
        if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
            $this->$property = $value;
        }
        return $this;
    }
}


class foo1 extends bar{
    public function someMethod() {
        $this->commonlib->addQueries($fromSomeWhere);
    }
}

class foo2 extends bar{
    public function someMethod() {
        $this->commonlib->addQueries($fromSomeWhereElseAndInADifferentWay);
    }
}

class main {

    public $commonlib = new commonlib();

    public function start(){
        //goal is to share one instance of $this->commonlib between foo1 and foo2 
        //so that they can both add to the properites of $this->commonlib (global
        //between the two)
        $foo1 = new foo1();
        $foo1->commonlib = $commonlib;

        $foo2 = new foo2();
        $foo2->commonlib = $commonlib;

        $foo1->someMethod();
        $foo2->someMethod();

        //now execute all of the queries after foo1 and foo2 add their query
        $this->commonlib->RunQueries();

}
```

Edit:

#### Approach 2: Pass common lib as an argument and only put algos in foo1 and foo2

Thus,

```
class foo1 {
    public function addQueries($commonlib) {
        $commonlib->addQueries($fromSomeWhere);
    }
}

class foo2 {
    public function addQueries($commonlib) {
        $commonlib->addQueries($fromSomeWhereElseAndInADifferentWay);
    }
}

class main {

    public $commonlib = new commonlib();

    public function start(){
        //goal is to share one instance of $this->commonlib between foo1 and foo2 
        //so that they can both add to the properites of $this->commonlib (global
        //between the two)
        $foo1 = new foo1();
        $foo2 = new foo2();

        $foo1->someMethod($commonlib);
        $foo2->someMethod($commonlib);

        //now execute all of the queries after foo1 and foo2 add their query
        $this->commonlib->RunQueries();

}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you are recommending that I pass `commonlib` into `foo1` construct and then saving it as a property inside of `bar`?

Comment: @Justin yes (in essence). Sorry, I am on a mobile device and cannot post code. Will post it shortly when I get to a PC.

Comment: OK...looking forward.

Comment: @Justin Added two example code stubs that you can re-use. I don't know PHP so there may be a few syntax errors here and there, hope you will recognize them and avoid them.

Comment: Wow, thank! Your examples are crystal clear. I think I am going to go with your first approach.

Comment: @justin glad I could help.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) the pattern you are looking for?

The singleton pattern allows you to have only one instance of an object. This instance can generally be called by every object or functions who need it and as it is a single instance every changes will be accessible everywhere.

Comment: Yes, however it is a 3rd party class and I was debating whether or not to create a singleton wrapper out of it or not....I would rather leave the class as it is.

Comment: Can't you just use inheritance from commonlib and use this new class as a Singleton?

Comment: It will solve the problem but I won't recommend it though. You should use the singleton pattern only when the design of the object itself mandates that it be singleton.

Comment: I don't know if reference mechanism exists in PHP but it would solve everything as you would just pass your commonlib as reference to your foo1 and foo2 object and both would link to the same commonlib object.